# How do I change switch-point percentages from 90% to 75% for code-coverage in PHPUnit?

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage

When I run my PHPUnit suite with coverage, I get this in the resulting HTML:

```
Legend
Low: 0% to 50% Medium: 50% to 90% High: 90% to 100%
Generated by PHP_CodeCoverage 2.0.13 using PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5 and PHPUnit 4.4.0 at Sun Dec 21 20:21:31 UTC 2014.
```

Are the 50% and 90% "switch-points" configurable (so I can change to 35% and 75% respectively)?
How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, these thresholds are configurable. Please refer to the [documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.logging) to learn about the `lowUpperBound` and `highLowerBound` settings.